# Unable to fetch data from third party api in NestJs showing Error 412

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to post data to some third party API I have added authkey correctly in my request headers but when I am making request its showing below error:

```
 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request failed with status code 412
```

Below is my Postman configuration for making Postman request:

[image]

[image]

Below is my code:

**subscribe.controller.ts**

```
@Controller()
export class SubscribeController {
constructor(private subscribeService:SubscribeService){}

@Post('location')
async getLocation(@Body('phoneNumber') phoneNumber:string){
   
    const loc = await this.subscribeService.getLocation(phoneNumber);
    return loc; 
  }
}
```

**subscribe.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SubscribeService {
constructor(@InjectModel('Subscribe') private readonly model:Model<Subscribe>,
            private httpService: HttpService){}

    async getLocation(phoneNumber:string){
   
    const data = {phoneNumber};  

    const url = 'https://example.com';
    const headersRequest = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };

      const resp = await this.httpService.post(url,data,{ headers: headersRequest }).pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return response.data;
        })
      );

      return resp;
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this request `const url = 'https://example.com';
    const headersRequest = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
`

works from postman individually? I would suggest debug the headers/body you are trying to send

Comment: yeah its working individually.

Comment: `headers/body` wat do u mean I am new to this could u please explain bit.

Comment: This is you body `const data = {phoneNumber};` and these are headers you are passing `const headersRequest = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authkey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };`

Something is not right when you pass them through your code
We need to check that

You can compare your postman curl and actual call made by your service

Comment: Where  can i get postman curl from

Comment: Try below updates and it that works for you
I think problem is with your request body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241889/discussion-between-digvijay-and-sohan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I would suggest you send body like this
Create following DTO class

```
    export class PhoneNumber 
    {
    phoneNumber:string
    }
```

Then, type with your API/controlloer

```
  @Post('location')
async getLocation(@Body() phoneNumberBody:PhoneNumber,
 @Headers('authkey') authkey:string)){
   
    const loc = await this.subscribeService.getLocation(phoneNumberBody,authkey);
    return loc; 
  }
}
```

Update the service to send body,

```
@Injectable()
export class SubscribeService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Subscribe') private readonly model:Model<Subscribe>,
                private httpService: HttpService){}

    async getLocation(phoneNumber:PhoneNumber,authkey:string){
        
        const url = 'https://example.com';
        const headersRequest = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'authkey': authkey 
        };

        const resp = await this.httpService.post(url,phoneNumber,{ headers: headersRequest }).pipe(
            map((response) => {
                return response.data;
            })
        );

        return resp;
    }
}
```

To make sure you are sending body in correct format, try to `console.log(phoneNumber);` in service call

Another thing we can try ot use axios request if that does not work

```
  const resp = await axios.post('https:<your-url>',phoneNumber,{headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'authkey': authkey
        }});

        console.log(resp.data);
     }
     catch(err){
         console.log(err);
     }
```

Comment: In console `phoneNumber` is coming but still coming same error after modifying the code.

Comment: Updated
 the answer to add headers in your call